# Why am I getting MissingMethodException in an Abstract class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have an abstract class and other classes that inherit from it.

Those classes are below:

```
[Table("Contents", Schema="Admon")]
    public abstract class Content
    {
        public Content()
        {
            this.EntryDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string InfoType { get; set; }
        public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
        public string Preview { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string CategoryID { get; set; }
        public int? DocID { get; set; }

        public virtual Content Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Content> Subs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photo : Content { }
    public class Notice : Content { }
    public class Article : Content { }
    public class Calendar : Content { }
```

My problem is that anytime i run my app it throws an exception that reads

```
System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class
```

What can I do to rectify this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use inheritance in Entity Framework, you have to implement TPH (Table per Hierarchy) or TPT (Table per Type) database structure.

With this strategy, you will be able to implement your expected behavior.
You can follow [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) to implement TPH or TPT, and learn about this technology.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of an abstract class. An abstract class contains abstract members which define what a subclass should contain.

If this class must remain abstract you need to create a second class that inherits from it and implements it's members and use *that* class to do your processing with.

If the class doesn't have to remain abstract (I can't see why it should be but without seeing the rest of your code I can't be 100% sure) then just remove the abstract keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The class **Content** would not compile because the your class is **abstract**. The MVC engine 
cannot create an instance of Content directly.Unless you give it some way to know which type of Problem to instantiate, there's nothing it can do.
       It is possible to create your own ModelBinder implementation, and tell MVC to use it. Your implementation could be tied to a Dependency Injection framework, for example, so that it knows to create a **Content1** whenever a **Content** class is requested.